# Pre/Post Analysis - questions about covariates

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, intervention-analysis, pre-post-comparison

I am trying to evaluate the impact of an intervention (0/1) on readmission rates pre- and post-intervention. Every individual has a pre-period rate and a post-period rate.

A few important points:
1. The duration of time that each patient's post-period rate covers is variable (between 90 days and 500 days). This is because the intervention is ongoing. 
2. For patients in the intervention group, there is variability in the number (and type) of intervention services they receive.

I intend to do a multiple regression in SPSS, dependent variable is the post rate and independent variables include pre rate, intervention services (y/n), and other variables.

My questions are:
1. Do I include the post-period duration as an independent variable?
2. Do I need to do two separate regression analyses - one that looks at the post rates for the intervention group vs the control group, with other independent variables including the pre-rate, and variables that are different between the groups (e.g., gender, age). Or, can I put everything into one model, such that I'll be able to tell the impact of no intervention, intervention with say 2-10, 11-20, or 21+ intervention services? How can I assess if it's the type of intervention services that's important as well? Do I need interaction effects? If the latter, what should be interacted and how do I interpret?